# Como insertar en una tabla valores que estan en otras tablas

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql-9.3

Hola recientemente me he topado con un problema donde necesito insertar en una tabla valores que se encuentran en distintas tablas he investigado y encontré lo que pudiera ser una solución pero me da error:

> una subconsulta utilizada como expresión retornó más de un registro.

La solución que encontré es:

```
INSERT INTO mod_hechos.dat_datosgenerales (iddatosgenerales1, 
                                           contenido1, 
                                           fecharegistro1,
                                           idusuarioregistro1,
                                           idclasificacioninformacion1,
                                           activo1, 
                                           idcapaincidencia1)
SELECT (SELECT iddatosgenerales FROM mod_incidencia.dat_datosgenerales),            
       (SELECT contenido FROM mod_incidencia.dat_datosgenerales), 
       (SELECT fecharegistro FROM mod_incidencia.incidencias), 
       (SELECT idusuarioregistro FROM mod_incidencia.dat_datosgenerales), 
       (SELECT idclasificacioninformacion FROM  mod_incidencia.dat_nef), 
       (SELECT activo FROM mod_incidencia.dat_datosgenerales), 
       (SELECT idcapaincidencia FROM mod_incidencia.dat_visibilidad);
```

Comment: También puedes guardar el resultado de la consulta en distintas variables y que se añadan, supongo que esta no es la mejor opción, lo comento por si te sirve de ayuda. Un saludo

Comment: Alguna (o todas) de tus subconsultas devuelve, para 1 solo registro, más de 1 valor. Supongo que es porque te faltan los respectivos where a cada una de ellas.

Comment: Normalmente habría una solución más óptima con una sola consulta y no tantas sub-consultas. El error, como ya te han dicho, es que alguna sub-consulta está devolviendo más de un registro y eso no es válido. La sugerencia sería que primero hagas una consulta _select_ que te devuelva una sola fila con los datos que te gustaría insertar. Sobre eso, se puede hacer un `insert/select`.

Comment: Si son multiples registros, no hay problema. La base es tener una consulta `select` que te devuelva la información tal como quieres que quede en la tabla destino.

Comment: lo que estoy intentando es insertar la columna completa que se encuentra en un a tabla dentro de otra tabla no insertar valor a valor. Originalmente eran 5 tablas y se redujeron a 2 y tengo que introducir los datos de esas 5 tablas en las 2 tablas nuevas y no se puede introducir uno a uno porque hay millones de datos en esas tablas

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que estás buscando es algo así:

```
    INSERT INTO mod_hechos.dat_datosgenerales (iddatosgenerales1, contenido1, fecharegistro1, idusuarioregistro1, idclasificacioninformacion1, activo1, idcapaincidencia1) 
values  (select iddatosgenerales from mod_incidencia.dat_datosgenerales where condicion traería 1 solo resultado, 
    select contenido from mod_incidencia.dat_datosgenerales where condicion traería 1 solo resultado, 
    select fecharegistro from mod_incidencia.incidencias where condicion traería 1 solo resultado, 
    select idusuarioregistro from mod_incidencia.dat_datosgenerales where condicion traería 1 solo resultado, 
    select idclasificacioninformacion from mod_incidencia.dat_nef where condicion traería 1 solo resultado,  
    select activo from mod_incidencia.dat_datosgenerales where condicion traería 1 solo resultado, 
    select idcapaincidencia from mod_incidencia.dat_visibilidad where condicion traería 1 solo resultado);
```

Si alguna de tus subconsultas trae más de 1 resultado, te marcará ese error que comentas.

Answer (score -1):

mmmm la verdad no estoy muy metido en el tema ya que no conosco la solucion que estas planteando pero yo lo haria de la siguiente manera pruebalo y me avisas si te resulto (te va a quedar un poco largo el codigo)

```
require_once "conexion.php";
$conexion=conexion();

$datos="select iddatosgenerales from mod_incidencia.dat_datosgenerales";
$result=mysqli_query($conexion,$datos);
$ver=mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$dato=$ver['iddatosgenerales'];

$datos2="select contenido from mod_incidencia.dat_datosgenerales";
$result=mysqli_query($conexion,$datos);
$ver=mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$dato2=$ver['contenido'];

$datos3="select fecharegistro from mod_incidencia.incidencias";
$result=mysqli_query($conexion,$datos);
$ver=mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$dato3=$ver['fecharegistro'];

$datos4="select idusuarioregistro from mod_incidencia.dat_datosgenerales";
$result=mysqli_query($conexion,$datos);
$ver=mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$dato4=$ver['idusuarioregistro'];

$datos5="select idclasificacioninformacion from mod_incidencia.dat_nef";
$result=mysqli_query($conexion,$datos);
$ver=mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$dato5=$ver['idclasificacioninformacion'];

$datos6="select activo from mod_incidencia.dat_datosgenerales";
$result=mysqli_query($conexion,$datos);
$ver=mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$dato6=$ver['activo'];

$datos7="select idcapaincidencia from mod_incidencia.dat_visibilidad";
$resmuni=mysqli_query($conexion,$datos);
$ver=mysqli_fetch_row($resmuni);
$dato7=$ver['idcapaincidencia'];

$sql= "INSERT INTO mod_hechos.dat_datosgenerales (iddatosgenerales1, contenido1, fecharegistro1, idusuarioregistro1, idclasificacioninformacion1, activo1, idcapaincidencia1) values ('$dato','$dato2','$dato3','$dato4','$dato5','$dato6','$dato7')";

echo $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
```

Comment: lo que estoy intentando es insertar la columna completa que se encuentra en un a tabla dentro de otra tabla no insertar valor a valor

Comment: ponelo un while que recorra toda la tabla y eso proceso seria el mismo si no me equivoco y que agarre todo lo que te pase require_once "conexion.php";
$conexion=conexion(); while(condicion){ todo el codigo de arriba };

Comment: Igual intenta con ese codigo sin el while que te pase porque si estoy en lo correcto lo va a generar tal cual lo pediste. de ultima si no funciona proba con el while

Comment: voy a probar a ver que pasa pero no le se micho a php. Gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: y? te funciono?